# Using ColdFusion to prevent history from being taken

Tags: coldfusion, browser-history

I'm fairly new to ColdFusion and am currently creating a system for which users can view PDF files. As well, I have it so some users can upload replacements for the current PDF if need be. The problem is, at least when using Firefox, when the user views the PDF file, it goes into their history cache to improve loading times I assume, and if a user replaces the PDF with a more updated one, users with the original PDF in their history cache will just see the old file and not the new one.

Now, I'm not going to just tell users to clear their history, so here's where my question comes in: Is there either a way to prevent the PDF from going into their history cache or is there a way to remove the page from the history? Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PDF link add timestamp using gettickcount() to make URL unique and this prevent caching pdf.

http://mywebsite/pdfname.pdf?123249329323

Answer (score 3):

Rather than link directly to the PDF, link to a .cfm that has this code:

```
<cfheader name="expires" value="#getHttpTimeString(now())#"> 
<cfheader name="pragma" value="no-cache"> 
<cfheader name="cache-control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"> 

<cfcontent file="#path_to_pdf_file#" type="application/pdf">
```

Comment: You forgot `GetHttpTimeString()` around `now()` for `expires`

Comment: There is one advantage of this approach over the one suggested above - here, if the PDF is displayed directly in the browser (with a PDF plugin), the user will be able to navigate away from the page and then return to it (with the "back" button) and be served the newer content.  If you implemented it as described by Pritesh, then the user would have to go back to the page containing the PDF link, refresh that page (to generate a new timestamp for the link), then click the link again.

Comment: What I originally had was that the PDF opened up in a new tab or window (depending on the browser). To test your theory, I opened up a PDF and it opened in a new tab. Then, with the tab still open, I submitted a newer version. Then I went to the tab with the old PDF and clicked refresh, and it changed to the new version that I just resubmitted, which is how it should be running. So I was able to do this without having to refresh the page with the link. I could just simply refresh the PDF tab and it changed accordingly. But I'll keep your method in mind. Thanks for your help as well! :D

Comment: @Nickyd - Refreshing the pdf is basically the same as refreshing the page with the link. Try clinking the link that opens the pdf twice. ie `<a href="pdfname.pdf?123249329323">`  Do you see the new pdf or the old one?

Comment: I click it the first time before uploading the new PDF, so it of course shows the old one. I click to upload a new PDF (which is done in a different tab). Then the click the very same link to the PDF (without even refreshing the page), and it will then take me to the new PDF. I'm kind of confused at how it manages to do that if the timestamp is the same, but I can't complain beings it's doing what I want it to do.

Comment: @Nickyd - Weird. Sounds like exactly what you were doing before, just minus the timestamp parameter (which didn't change) ;)